# objective-c - cast id to entity object by using Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, entity, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to do a very generic tool where I can set properties with the Key-Value coding pattern.

In my generic tool, I know the class name of the entity concerned (NSManagedObject).
I have also that entity with `id` type.

**GenericToolViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Class className;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id  entity;
```

When I set my generic tool, I initialise it that way :

I initialise that view controller in  :

**AnotherViewController.m**

```
GenericToolViewController *genericToolViewController = [[GenericToolViewController alloc] initWithClassName:[myEntity class]];
genericToolViewController.entity = [[myEntity alloc] init];
```

After a submit button, I'm trying to set a property thank to the property name.

With `id` type, it's not possible for me to set any value. I need to tell witch type it is.

I tried to do something like this :

```
(self.className *)[self.entity setValue:textField forKeyPath:propertyName];
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't compile. But I'm trying to cast `id` with the type that I have in `self.className` . Is it possible ?

Each entity can have different names of properties... I don't how I can make it... 
I can't make a if statement, and to check the class with `isKindOfClass` because it wouldn't be generic anymore if I display `myEntity` class in that controller.

I hope that I explained well my problem
If you have any idea how to resolve it please.

Thanks,

Sandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the class name, and I use the Key Value coding pattern by having a NSManagedObject. 
I could make it very generic thanks to that. with the Key Value coding, we don't need to precise the type of the class. So I put difficulties on myself for nothing :).